# XMLHttpRequest functions Javascript working once

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

First of all, I know this question is everywhere on forums but still, no solution worked fine for me. So I'll try to explain as much as I can.

**Goal :** I'm trying to create a game using a MVC pattern and using Javascript to make the main page not reloading thanks to XMLHttprequests. When you arrive at the game page, you have the riddle 1 which is displayed and waiting for your input. Then with some arrows I want to go to riddle 2 or 3 or more or less without reloading the page (because I want a background music be played throughout).

**My problem :** I made some XHR tests : when I click on the *Update* button, all the components are loading and I'm in awe. Then I try the *Update2* button. Nothing happens. Also I don't want to use JQuery (let pure Javascript be).

**What I already tried :** I learnt about the cache problem and tried to correct it with some random number in the url I'm sending in XHRequest. Also changed the *let* into *var* and vice-versa but no effect (I'm new I don't know the effects of one or the other yet). I isolated the generating XHR object into a function.

**My files were the issues are** (I didn't write a lot of components because it is redundant) :

*MAIN TEMPLATE :*

```
[...]
<body>
    <!-- THOSE BUTTONS ARE TESTS FOR XMLHttprequests -->
    <button onclick="UpdateAllComponents(1)">Update</button> <!-- riddle 1 -->
    <button onclick="UpdateAllComponents(2)">Update2</button> <!-- riddle 2 -->

    <!-- Number of the riddle displayed -->
    <span id="numberRiddle"></span>

    <!-- Go back to the previous riddle -->
    <span id="previousRiddle"></span>

    <!-- Go to the next riddle -->
    <span id="nextRiddle"></span>

    <!-- Description riddle and answer form -->
    <span id="answerForm"></span>

    <!-- Message saying if the answer entered is the good one or not -->
    <span id="validationRiddle"></span>

    <!-- Tip that appears after a moment -->
    <span id="tip"></span>

    <script src="public/js/updatePlayComponents.js"></script>

</body>
```

*MY JS FILE*

```
"use strict"

function createXHRequest() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    return xhr;
}

function UpdateComponentNumberRiddle(numberRiddle) {
    let xhr = createXHRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "index.php?action=play&numberRiddle="+numberRiddle+"&rand="+Math.floor(Math.random()*100), true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("numberRiddle").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };

    xhr.send();   
}

            [...] ALMOST THE SAME KIND OF FUNCTION FOR EVERY COMPONENT [...]

function UpdateComponentAnswerForm(idRiddle) {
    let xhr = createXHRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "index.php?action=play&answerForm="+idRiddle+"&rand="+Math.floor(Math.random()*100), true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("answerForm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };

    xhr.send();   
}

function UpdateAllComponents(numberRiddle)
{
    UpdateComponentNumberRiddle(numberRiddle);
    UpdateComponentPreviousRiddle(numberRiddle);
    UpdateComponentNextRiddle(numberRiddle);
    UpdateComponentAnswerForm(numberRiddle);
    UpdateComponentValidationRiddle(numberRiddle);
    UpdateComponentTip(numberRiddle);
}
```

I don't know if it will be useful but here is my router:

```
    else if($_GET['action'] == "play")
            {                    
                // COMPONENTS
                if(isset($_GET['numberRiddle'])) 
                {
                    GetNumberRiddle($team, $_GET['numberRiddle']);
                }
                [...] NOT WRITING EVERYTHING [...]
                else if(isset($_GET['answerForm'])) 
                {
                    GetAnswerForm($team, $_GET['answerForm']);
                }
                else Play($team);
            }
    [...]
```

And to finish an example of one of my component controller :

```
function GetNumberRiddle($team, $idRiddle)
{
    $gamestate = new Game($team->getIdTeam());
    $totalRiddles = $gamestate->GetTotalRiddles();
    $riddle = $gamestate->GetRiddleInfos($idRiddle);

    require('src/view/components/play/numberRiddle.php');
}
```

And the view associated :

```
<span>
Vous etes a l'enigme <?php echo $riddle[4] . "/" . $totalRiddles;?>
</span>
```

Thank you for taking the time to understand what does not work and how can I fix that. Understand that I'm totally new in : Javascript, MVC, OOP. I really don't know why I decided to do that in such a way (learn definitely), but everything worked fine until I decided to put some XHR in it.

I'm glad for doing this and I really looked for hours for an answer to my problem. Please can someone help me ?

Good night for those like me who never sleep and good morning to others

**EDIT : **
Now it works because im my model the function GetRiddleInfos() didn't take into account the parameter (I forgot it) so nothing was fetched. I'll be more careful next time...

Comment: are you certain the php code on the server is returning responseText? If using chrome, have you opened up the inspector under developer tools to ensure you're  getting a 200 response status? I see you only have a condition catching for a successful response. What about if there is an error? are there any errors being logged in the console of the browser when you click the second button?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. In my console no error at all when I click on both. Note that if I click on button 2 then when I reload the whole page the button 1 will display what button 2 displays. Playing with some console(log) and throwing errors : 1) my function are well called as many times as I click on the button, with the numberRiddle well taken into account if it's button 1 or 2. 2) I am indeed getting a 200 response status for each button.
No error at all, I don't understand why. Also, when I try some 'alert("ddfd")' in the JS function nothing happens so maybe it's a display issue ?

Comment: Hi again, I edit my post I found the issue

Comment: Your answer didn't provide anything to my question. Thanks for the tips though, I will look at that another day